# Can we identify if 2 events $A$ and $B$ are independent (or dependent) without knowing $P(A \cap B)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

[image]

The above diagram certainly tells us that that the 2 events $A$ and $B$ are not mutually exclusive. But what do we know for sure about their independence. Can we tell anything about their independence without knowing the values for $P(A \cap B)$ .

Let $P(A) = 0.4$ and $P(B) = 0.8$

Comment: You can obtain upper and lower bounds on $P(A \cap B)$; the independence case sits not too far from the middle of those bounds.

Comment: Can you give me the upper and lower bounds for this particular example ? And also, the venn diagrams tell us nothing about independence correct ? Only knowing what $A$ and $B$ , or the value of $P(A∩B)$ can tell us anything about independence ? These are the main questions I have

Comment: Note that P(A) + P(B) = 1.2. Clearly you can't have a probability > 1. How large is the smallest allowed P(A∩B)  to keep P(A∪B)  a valid probability? By the same token, what's the largest possible P(A∩B)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can identify two variables are independent instead by checking if

$P(A|B) = P(A)$

For all possible values of $A$ and $B$

Comment: What is the definition of $P(A\mid B)$? and how can anyone check whether or not $P(A\mid B)$ equals $P(A)$ or not without first determining the value of $P(A\cap B)$ as a first step in calculating the value of $P(A\mid B)$?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot tell something about two events $A, B$ independence if you just know the marginal probabilities $P(A), P(B)$. If you also had information in the probability of union $P(A\cup B)$ then you might could say something with the formula $P(A\cup B)= P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$. Otherwise, there are two unknown quantities in this formula.

However, the only case that I can think of that you can do that is, if you have that $P(A)=1$ and $P(B)=0$.

From the probability axioms, it is known that the probability of the entire space will be equal to $1$, i.e. $P(\Omega)=1=P(A)$.

We also know that $P(\Omega)= 1- P(\Omega^{c})$, where $\Omega \cap \Omega^{c}=\varnothing$. In this case $P(\Omega^{c})=P(B)=0$.

So, in this particular case we can identify that $A\cap B=\varnothing \Rightarrow P(A\cap B)=0$ they are independent.